# Projecting a 2d noise texture to a 3d sphere in Shader Graph (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-development, shader-graph

I am having trouble trying to seamlessly match a 2d noise texture to a 3d sphere I have created and imported into Unity. I am using Shader Graph since I know nothing about actually programming shaders.

I've tried to blend the noise at different rotations, yet it just looks like a blurred mess. It ends up creating these circular patterns.

[image]

I am unsure if maybe I am using the wrong blend or misunderstand what the rotation is actually doing to the texture.

Here is my shader graph. RotateProjection has the following values (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0). RotateProjection (1) has the following values (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 90). Do note however in these pictures the bottom group is not connected to the output at all. Noise Scale is set to 10.
[image]

Here are 2 pictures of the sphere. The first one is how I want it look all around with seamless wrapping. The second is what is actually happening.
[image]
[image]